# php preg_replace need help

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have created a function to search through strings and replace keywords in those strings with links. I am using

```
preg_replace('/\b(?<!=")(?<!=\')(?<!=)(?<!=&quot;)(?<!>)(?<!&gt;)' . $keyword . '(?!</a)(?!&lt;/a)\b', $newString, $row);
```

which is working as expected. The only issue is that if someone had a link like this

```
<a href="www.domain.tdl/keyword.html">Luxury Automobile sales</a>
```

`Automobile` being our `$keyword` in this example.

It would end up looking like

```
<a href="www.domain.tdl/keyword.html">Luxury <a href="www.domain.tdl/keywords.html">Automobile</a> Sales</a>
```

You can understand my frustration.
Not being confident in regex I thought I would ask if anyone here would know a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: don't use regular expressions for html …

Answer (score 3):

How about a proper HTML parser like [DOMDocument?](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
$html = '<a href="www.domain.tdl/keyword.html">Luxury Automobile sales</a>';
$dom  = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
  $node->nodeValue = str_replace('Automobile', 'Cars', $node->nodeValue);
  echo simplexml_import_dom($node)->asXML();
}
```

Is not a problem to get element attribute too

```
foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
  $attr = $node->getAttributeNode('href');
  $attr->value = str_replace('Automobile', 'keyword', $attr->value);
  echo simplexml_import_dom($node)->asXML();
}
```

Comment: From looking at that I gather it looks at each a link and replaces certain text in it. This is not what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to wrap any instance of a keyword with a link. The issue is if the keyword is wrapped with other words and those words are wrapped with a link (Like the original example) it will still wrap the keyword with a link so I will end up with a double link.

Comment: @Jack - do you mean `<a href="www.domain.tdl/Automobile.html">Luxury Automobile sales</a>` ?

Comment: Basically, i am using `preg_replace` to turn `Automobile` into `<a href="www.domain.tdl/Automobile.html">Automobile</a>`. That works fine, but if there is already a link like `<a href="www.domain.tdl/Automobile.html">Luxury Automobile sales</a>` my `preg_replace` will turn it into `<a href="www.domain.tdl/Automobile.html">Luxury <a href="www.domain.tdl/Automobile.html">Automobile</a> sales</a>`